# Handling exception using exceptionally on a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

I am handling exceptions occurred during the `messageProcessingService.processMessage(messageObject)` method call using **exceptionally** method.
Still, the eclipse is asking me to handle the exception at  the method call
`messageProcessingService.processMessage(messageObject);`

The `processMessage` method throws `CheckedException`.

Why does this happen? How can I handle it using **exceptionally** alone

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->{
  return messageProcessingService.processMessage(messageObject);
}).thenAccept(response ->{

  if (response.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
    log.debug("Sent Message");
    deleteMessage(messageObject);

  } else {
    log.debug("Cannot send Message");
  }

}).exceptionally(ex ->{

  throw new MessageNotSendException(ex);

});
```

Comment: Because `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` takes a `Supplier`, and a `Supplier.get` doesn't allow checked exceptions to be thrown. You could make `messageProcessingService.processMessage` throw a runtime exception instead.

Comment: Note that it doesn't necessarily make sense to throw an exception from the `exceptionally` handler. It is used to handle exceptions, not to throw them. And those handlers will not be executed in the context where you define in, but in whatever executor currently continues your future.

Comment: There is no advantage in splitting this trivial code into three stages. You can use a single code block, i.e. `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { try { Response response = messageProcessingService.processMessage(messageObject); if(response.getStatus().equals("OK")) { log.debug("Sent Message"); deleteMessage(messageObject); } else log.debug("Cannot send Message"); } catch(Exception ex} { throw new CompletionException(new MessageNotSendException(ex)); })`